# Why there is always a number $b \in Z$ s.t $(\frac{b}{p})=-1$ for prime $p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Out teacher said that for any odd prime $p$ there exists a number $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $(\frac{b}{p})=-1$ (We are talking about legendre symbol here).
Intuitively I can understand why, but a short proof will be much better. Thanks!

Comment: Have you learned the primitive roots? Namely, do you know that $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$ is always cyclic for prime $p$?

Comment: @awllower yes, indeed

Comment: Just show that the map $x\mapsto x^2$ is not onto $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$.  Hint: $1^2 = (-1)^2$.

Comment: Then you know that a primitive root is one such element, right?

Comment: For $x$ between $1$ and $p-1$, let $f(x)$ be the remainder when $x^2$ is divided by $p$. It is not hard to show that this map is $2$ to $1$, so in fact $(a/p)=-1$ for half of the numbers $a$ between $1$ and $p-1$. Of course the prime cannot be $2$, But conveniently $(a/p)$ is only defined for odd primes.

Comment: @awllower hmmm.. so if $b$ is a primitive root, $b^{p-1} \equiv 1 (mod p)$ and $b^\frac{p-1}{2} \not\equiv 1 (mod p)$ thus $b^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -1 (mod p)$?

Comment: Yes, this is right. Also other comments are short enough, and much more elementary.

Comment: @ErickWong,André Nicolas: This is too complicated for me I'm afraid... But I can see now what my teacher did to prove that half the numbers are quadratic residues: for the equation $x^\frac{p-1}{2}=1$ there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ solutions. So there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues, and $\frac{p-1}{2}$ non quadratic residues...

Comment: bomba, you can write that up as an answer --- that's encouraged on this site. Then, sometime later, you can accept it. Helps clear the list of Unanswered Questions.

Comment: @bomba6 My suggestion is no more complicated than counting.  There are $p$ different residues mod $p$, but when you square them you get less than $p$ different values (because of overlaps).  Obviously there are some residues that are not the square of anything, which is exactly what you are trying to prove.  By contrast the existence of primitive roots is a bit more subtle.

Comment: Well, the prime $\,p\,$ **must** be odd...

Answer (score 4):

I'm writing the answer that I find the most easy for me:
Let $b$ be a primitive root for $p$ (there is always one). Thus $b^{p-1}\equiv 1 (p)$, and $b^\frac{p-1}{2} \not\equiv 1 (p)$ thus we must get $b^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv -1 (p)$.
From Legendre symbol we know that $(\frac{b}{p})\equiv b^\frac{p-1}{2} (p)$ so we proved that for every $p$ there exists $b$ s.t.$(\frac{b}{p})=-1$.